# Python/Selenium: How to grab value from the HTML?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to grab some values from the following code example but am unable to get a successful answer.

Using the US Patent and Trademark Office's website with a random trademark entered in this [link](https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=85931937&caseSearchType=US_APPLICATION&caseType=DEFAULT&searchType=statusSearch). I want to grab the Registration Date which has a value of May 12, 2015

```
    <div class="double table">
        <div class="row">
               <div class="key">US Serial Number:</div>
               <div class="value">85931937</div>
               <div class="key">Application Filing Date:</div>
               <div class="value">May 14, 2013</div>
        </div>
       
        <div class="row">
               <div class="key">US Registration Number:</div>
               <div class="value">4735834</div>
               <div class="key">Registration Date:</div>
               <div class="value">May 12, 2015</div>
        </div>
```

Notice this would be the fourth time the class name `value` is being called in the code example and is nested within other div classes.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
values = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'value')
print(values[3])
```

but values returns an empty list `[]`

Please advise on what I am doing wrong, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the text *`May 12, 2015`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='key' and text()='Registration Date:']//following-sibling::div[1]").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='key' and text()='Registration Date:']//following-sibling::div[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: XPATH and getattribute("innerHTML") did the trick, thank you! Solved.